# What is a potential well?

Tags: classical-mechanics, potential, potential-energy, definition

What exactly is a [*potential well*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potential_well) physically?  [I've read the linked Wiki article, but it doesn't answer my questions, such as, what does it mean for a particle to "move along a potential" and "roll down potential"? How does this correspond to the particles actual motion in space?]

I've read many examples where the author talks of a particle being trapped in a potential well and requiring a certain amount of energy to "climb" out of it, but how does this relate to the particle's actual motion, and how does it become "captured" in a potential well?

Heuristically, is it simply the case that a potential well is present in a particular region of space due to a action of a force in that region of space. The force acts on particles within that region and so this requires a given particle to do work against the force if it is to carry on along its original trajectory. If the particle has less energy available to it than the energy required to overcome the force acting on it (i.e. its kinetic energy is less than the potential energy associated with the force) then the particle will be "trapped in the potential well", i.e. confined to travel within the region in which the force is acting along trajectories prescribed by the action of the force. If the particles kinetic energy is greater than the potential energy (associated with the force), then it won't be "trapped in the potential well" and will be able to "escape" the region of space in which the force is acting.

As an example, in simple harmonic motion (SHM), a spring is subject to a restoring force $F=-kx$ and this has an associated potential $V=\frac{1}{2}kx^{2}$. The potential well is then a quadratic, with the minimum describing the equilibrium configuration of the spring. The spring then oscillates about the minimum of the potential - compressing as it moves up one side of the potential (hence gaining potential energy and losing kinetic energy), then moving back to the minimum of the potential well (losing potential energy and gaining potential energy) and then stretching as it moves up the other side of the potential (again gaining potential energy and losing kinetic energy). It then repeats this in an oscillatory fashion.

Comment: What's your question? If you go to your wikipedia link in the very beginning there's "A potential well is the region surrounding a local minimum of potential energy." That's more or less the definition.

Comment: @OON  Yes, I did read that, but I was hoping to get some physical intuition as to what it means for an object to be "trapped" in a potential well, and what it means for an object to "escape" a potential well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the top of a hill and dig a hole and but a ball in it. The ball must *rise* to exit the hole, before it can fall freely all the way down.

This is a potential well. A barrier. Your spring example is correct; though with the comment that the spring will *never* exit that potential well (there is nowhere to exit to - there is no maximum potential energy - it is not a "hole", which the string can get out from).

Comment: The problem I have is that in most cases the potential well isn't a physical well, i.e. is isn't some sort of hole that objects fall into. I'm hoping to get some physical intuition as to what it corresponds to? Is it simply this case that a potential exists in a particular region in space due to a force acting within that region, and then a potential well is a region surrounding a local minimum of the potential within the full region (in which the potential exists), with objects within this potential well having less energy than the potential energy outside this local region...

Comment: ... The trajectories of the objects within a potential well are then bounded by the force acting on them as they do not have enough energy to overcome the action of this force. Is it correct to say that an object can "climb" out of a potential well if it gains enough energy such that its energy is equal to (or greater than the potential energy outside the potential well), which corresponds to it having enough energy to overcome the force acting on it?!

Comment: @user35305 Everything you say is correct. The physical intuitive explanation you ask for is what I tried to give with an example here in the answer. Every time you encounter a potential well, you can always just think "Oh yea, that's just like the ball in a hole on a hill"; the principle is always like this. Something is "trapped" in a potential well, because it is a local minimum; a local stable equilibrium. What exactly is your doubt about this concept?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not entirely sure! I started thinking about the concept earlier on toady and managed to convince myself that I don't really understand it. I think it's the notion of something "rolling" down a potential being depicted as a particle rolling down the curve of potential. I'm unsure as to why the particle "rolls" down the potential in the first place? The potential is present due to the existence of a force acting, so is it simply that the force acting on the particle "pushes" it towards a local minimum of the potential?

Comment: @user35305 Yes, you can say it like that. The potential well is a a result of forces pushing the object there. Imagine 2 forces pushing towards each other. The point in the middle between them is the well where an object finds rest (equilibrium). If it moves to the sides, the force pushes it back. But the force might not be infinitely far stretching - if the object can move *against* this force far enough to get out of its reach, it is free. Out of the well. This point is then also am equilibrium, but an unstable one. If the object moves even further, another force takes over and pulls in...

Comment: ... it. The object is now out of the well and can be pulled by this other force freely. This other force might have been working at the same time as the forces causing the well, so everything I just explained is just with this external force superimposed. The equilibriums are them the point where all forces cancel out etc.

Comment: What do people mean when they say that a particle "rolls" down a potential? Is this just analogous to what we've discussed above, i.e. the particle is "pushed" towards the local minimum of the potential by the force acting on it, and hence "rolls" down the slope of the potential gaining kinetic energy and losing potential energy?!

Comment: @user35305 Exactly. "Rolls" is just physics slang, because the curve looks so roll'able. And "roll" fits well to my example above, but that's just an example. Don't worry about that. Everything you've described is correct, so you seem to have gotten it

Answer (score 4):

A potential well is basically the energy required to be in a certain position. For example, if you have a hole, and a ball in the hole, it will require a certain energy for it to get up and out of the hole. However, if it does not have that energy, it's stuck at the bottom of a hole. Here's an illustration of this:

[image]

This is a basic example, but another could be something like a gravity well, as in General Relativity. Just think of spacetime as having a dip in it...it requires whatever object, the Moon, say, a certain amount of energy to get out of that dip and escape the Earth's orbit.

Now, quantum mechanics makes this all a little more interesting. Just like before, if you have, say, a particle, it requrires a certain energy to get out of the potential well. Believe it or not, this occurs in the atom, because of the strong nuclear force. Within the nucleus, it is practically impossible for the protons and neutrons to get out because of the strong nuclear force, but once they get just out of range, they can leave very quickly. A diagram of this is shown below:

[image]

Now, you might ask, what in the universe is that little arrow that goes *through* the potential well? Isn't the whole point that the particle can't just get through that? Well, actually, in the weird and whacky world of the quantum, it can, and it's called quantum tunneling. The particle has a chance of just kind of sneaking through the barrier, and popping out on the other side before the universe notices anything wrong. Quantum tunneling makes nuclear fusion possible, and is one of the phenomenon that makes people look at QM a little funny.

Hope this helps!